Movie where man and woman compete who has more scars
It was a movie with man and woman, both in police or some other profession which involved danger. And there was a tension between those two. There was some scene where they were in the room, trying to impress the other with battle scars. It ended them being naked. What was the name of the movie/serial? Wasn't it Dempsey and Makepeace?

It's not the answer, but reminds me a bit of a similar scene in Chasing Amy, which itself is an homage to a scene in Jaws.

@SteveMelnikoff, great! Can you please provide some link or some more detailed instructions how to find it?

Chasing Amy scene (note: dialogue not safe for work!!). Jaws scene.

That sounds very much like a scene (YouTube clip) from Lethal Weapon 3 in which Riggs (Mel Gibson) and Cole (Rene Russo) show off their various knife, bullet and auto accident wounds.  There's definitely some sexual tension: "Yours is bigger than mine?  I don't think so!"

homage to Jaws but Dreyfus isn't sexy

@DForck42 I know you need statistics but you should be patient. I wait strategically so that he gets more upvotes (and also the question receives more attention)

@tomas... huh?  if it's the correct answer and you know it is then you should accept.  Most people don't decide to upvote or not based on if a question has been accepted or not, but rather if they agree with the answer.

@Tomas And in which way does the question need more attention once it has a correct, definite, and accepted answer?
